# No visible @ interface declares the selector "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Im getting `no visible @ interface for "ICMinorWorksPart1" declares the selector "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated"` at the following:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and I just cant work out what compiler is complaining of?

.h

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface ICMinorWorksPart1 : ICCertificateComponent   <UITextViewDelegate,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>

.....
```

.m

```
 #import "ICMinorWorksPart1.h"




@implementation ICMinorWorksPart1
@synthesize dateMinorWorksCompletedField=_dateMinorWorksCompletedField;
@synthesize certificateReferenceField=_certificateReferenceField;
@synthesize clientField=_clientField;
@synthesize detailsOfDeparturesField=_detailsOfDeparturesField;
@synthesize descriptionOfMinorWorksField=_descriptionOfMinorWorksField;
@synthesize addressOfTheMinorWorks=_addressOfTheMinorWorks;

 - (id)initWithCertificate:(Certificate *)certificate
 {




if ((self = [super initWithCertificate:certificate])) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MinorWorksPart1" owner:self options:nil];
    self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

    self.dateMinorWorksCompletedField.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"dateMinorWorksCompleted"]).value;

    DebugLog(@"dateMinorWorksCompleted attribute value is %@", ([self attributeWithName:@"dateMinorWorksCompleted"]).value);
    DebugLog(@"Certificate reference is %@", self.certificate.reference);
    self.certificateReferenceField.text = (self.certificate.reference != nil ? self.certificate.reference : @"");
    self.clientField.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"client"]).value;
    self.detailsOfDeparturesField.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"detailsOfDepartures"]).value;
    self.addressOfTheMinorWorks.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"addressOfTheMinorWorks"]).value;
    self.descriptionOfMinorWorksField.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"descriptionOfMinorWorks"]).value;
 }
return self;





 }

- (void)save
 {
([self attributeWithName:@"dateMinorWorksCompleted"]).value = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.dateMinorWorksCompletedField.textField.text];
DebugLog(@"dateMinorWorksCompleted value is %@", self.dateMinorWorksCompletedField.textField.text);
self.certificate.reference = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.certificateReferenceField.text];
([self attributeWithName:@"client"]).value = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.clientField.text];
([self attributeWithName:@"detailsOfDepartures"]).value = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.detailsOfDeparturesField.text];
([self attributeWithName:@"addressOfTheMinorWorks"]).value = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.addressOfTheMinorWorks.text];
([self attributeWithName:@"descriptionOfMinorWorks"]).value = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.descriptionOfMinorWorksField.text];
 }





//add adress
- (IBAction)addAddressBtn:(id)sender {


ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =

[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];


}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:


(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }


 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

[self displayPerson:person];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

return NO;
}

 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
 (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property
                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ICMinorWorksPart1` class's superclass (`ICCertificateComponent`) is not a subclass of `UIViewController` then the error is true as `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is a method of the `UIViewController` class.

In addition, both the `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` methods of the `UIViewController` class are deprecated in iOS 6 so you may want to take note of that as well.

Comment: Ah ok, I need to support iOS 5, i did note its depreciated in iOs 6. So if I want to keep iOS 5 support, can I do anything about this?

Comment: The new methods for presenting and dismissing were added in iOS 5.0 so you are good to use the new methods in place of the deprecated ones.